# Correctly redefine \eqref to allow post- and pre- text

Tags: macros, amsmath, robust-commands

From `amsmath.dtx`, the original definition is:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
```

I would like to redefine it so as to have post- and pre- text in the parentheses. My current code is the following:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand \eqref { O{} O{} m }
  {
    \textup { \tagform@ { #2 \ref{#3} #1 } }
  }
```

However, the original definition uses `DeclareRobustCommand` which makes the command robust (though I don't know what does this mean). Do I need to do something similar with my version above? Also, is it wise to include this modified definition in a package?

Comment: Commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\RenewDocumentCommand` are already robust.

Comment: Commands which trigger actions that do not take place in the stage of expansion but take place in later stages - such actions could be performing assignments for defining scratch-macros or incrementing counters or creating boxes or triggering `\write` - don't work out in pure-expansion-contexts where everything should be done via expansion only. E.g., `\edef` and `(\immediate)\write` with a moving argument like a .toc-entry are pure-expansion-contexts. A robust macro is intended not to expand in such contexts - the macro-token shall stay in place as is in such contexts.

Comment: ... the macro-token shall stay in place as is in such contexts. With new LaTeX-engines there is the `\protected`-prefix when defining macros. A macro defined in terms of `\protected` won't expand while `\edef/\xdef/\write` takes place. The LaTeX-kernel also has the oldschool-protection-mechanism: A token `\protect` is redefined according to the situation by macros `\protected@edef`/`\protected@write` and macros defined in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand` or with the token `\protect` prepended as result of expansion deliver a non-expanded or stringified representation of themselves.